# Google is not allowing the scope mail.google.com using OAuth php library

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api, google-authentication

Google is not allowing the scope "mail.google.com" when login through google and other scopes like gmail.readonly and gmail.send not working using OAuth php library. SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Could you provide more context?

Comment: Are you using socialite? or how exactly are you linking it? do you have the code that causes the error?

Comment: while login from my application google sent the error that "As a general rule choose the most restrictive scope possible, as users more readily grant access to limited, clearly described scopes.Thus we recommend you to consider using the following scopes that are necessary to implement your app's feature." https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly Instead or using the scope you have requested https://mail.google.com. For reference, a full list of OAuth scopes can b found on the page(the url was given)

Comment: yes i am using socialite and tried different scopes